# Drawing text on canvas with WINGDING.ttf font is not working on android

Tags: android, image, typeface, drawtext

When I am drawing Text with custom font(basically icon ex: WINGDING.ttf) using drawText is showing simple text as provided.

Steps I followed:
1. Added font file to Assets folder
2. Set paint with the added font
3. drawing text with the paint

To draw text I used the corresponding English character

```
canvas.drawText("p",0,1, x, y, myPaint);
```

This displays as p on app

Answer (score 2):

use this way if you have assets/fonts:

```
    private Paint    myPaint= new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);  
    private Typeface mFace; 
    mFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/WINGDING.ttf");  
    myPaint.setTextSize(32);
    myPaint.setTypeface(mFace);
    canvas.drawText("test test",0,1, x, y, myPaint);
  //canvas.drawText("test test", 10, 200, myPaint);
```

example:

```
private static class MyView extends View   
    {  
private Paint    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);  
private Typeface mFace;  
public MyView(Context context)   
{  
super(context);   
mFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/WINGDING.ttf");  
mPaint.setTextSize(32);  
}  
 @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)   
{   
mPaint.setTypeface(mFace);  
canvas.drawText("p p p p", 10, 200, mPaint);  
}  
}
```

Comment: I tried following code as per your comment but getting same result:
class MyView extends View
    {
     Paint myPaint;
  public MyView(Context context) {
   super(context);
   Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/WINGDING.ttf");
   myPaint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
   myPaint.setTypeface(face);
   myPaint.setTextSize(30);
   myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  }
  @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);
   canvas.drawText("p", 50, 50, myPaint);
  }
    }

Comment: still same result: text "p p p p" corresponds to some font icon in WINGDING font but it is displaying p p p p

Comment: code is right try by using any other font instead of WINGDING

Comment: I tried following fonts:</br>
WAKER___.TTF -> works,  </br>
WEBDINGS.TTF -> did not work,</br> 
WINGDING.ttf -> did not work</br>
one difference is there in these fonts WAKER___.TTF should display p as p but WEBDINGS.TTF & WINGDING.ttf should display p as icon text

Comment: my problem is WEBDINGS.TTF should display text icon, means corresponding text for characters(ex: p) but it displays same character as it is. i.e instead of using the custom font(WEBDINGS.TTF) it is using default font while displaying</br> Typeface always works for me if not using icon fonts

Answer (score 0):

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29643374/1364759) that linked this font converter, http://www.freefontconverter.com.

I took my .ttf font that would not render and converted it to .ttf again (so .ttf to .ttf) and now it works! I hope this helps!