# Android custom fonts Lollipop

Tags: java, android, fonts, android-5.0-lollipop, custom-font

I have two TextView which I want to put a custom font on.

In the OnCreate of my MainActivity, after the setContentView call, I wrote the following code:

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/BernerBasisschrift1.ttf");
TextView welcomeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome_message);
TextView introTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.introduction_message);

welcomeTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);        
introTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

But for some reason, the font stays default.

The app runs on Galaxy S6 Edge device (Lollipop 5.0.2).

I read [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=608) that there's a problem with custom fonts on Lollipop, and in order to fix it I converted my font with the tool provided in the thread to ttx and vice versa, but even this didn't help.

Any ideas what can I do?

Edit:
Tested on Jellybean (4.3), not working either.

**Another edit:
It works on a clean new project! Cant figure out the difference.
Putting the MainActivity and its' XML for help:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private LoginFragment loginFragment;
private TextView welcomeTextView;
private TextView introTextView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    hideActionBar();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    welcomeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome_message);
    introTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.introduction_message);

    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/BernerBasisschrift1.ttf");
    welcomeTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
    introTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, loginFragment, "facebookFragment").commit();

    }

}


@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    if(hasFocus){
        // get all views on screen
        ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>()
        {{
            add(findViewById(R.id.welcome_message));
            add(findViewById(R.id.introduction_message));
            add(findViewById(R.id.below_login));
            add(findViewById(R.id.above_login));
            add(findViewById(R.id.authButton));
            add(findViewById(R.id.logo));
        }};

        // set animations
        for(View view : views)
            YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(700).playOn(view);

    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void hideActionBar(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        getActionBar().hide();
}
```

And the activity's XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_background">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="256dp"
    android:layout_height="101dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/logo" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/welcome_message"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        style="@style/ShadowStyleText"
        android:gravity="center" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/introduction_message"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/introduction_message"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/ShadowStyleText"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_login_chunk"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" 
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/above_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/above_login_button"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        style="@style/ShadowStyleText"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/above_login"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/below_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/below_login_button"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        style="@style/ShadowStyleText"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does it work on pre-Lollipop devices?

Comment: @BidhanA I cannot know right now, I got no other phone around. But this is very simple, it should...

Comment: Do you have your font file inside of the font folder in your assets directory?

Comment: @BidhanA yes, as you can see in the code: getAssets() and fonts/font_name.ttf ...

Comment: @Jjang yes its in code. but do you make sure your fonts/BernerBasisschrift1.ttf is there in your assets folder? also If you don't have pre lollipop device you should check on any pre lollipop emulator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269264/custom-fonts-not-working-in-lollipop

Comment: @QadirHussain I will check this asap..

Comment: @IITAmiya Also tried that already.. no luck

Comment: @Jjang Another way . Please use otf format instead ttf

Comment: @IITAmiya otf not working either.

Comment: Just tested on Jellybean (4.3) and it's not working either...

Comment: @Jjang "other phones" are kind of irrelevant. Grab yourself a copy of Android Studio, install it, run the AVD, and make some Android Virtual Devices for the various versions of Android, then confirm.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans K it works on a clean project. Now what?

Comment: clean project run in... what? Every version of Android? Start updating your question with you test results, so that people who find your question have this new information immediately available to answer your question.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think the 'test on all versions' is useless, since I run the clean empty project on my phone, and font works. I run my full project with it, and it doesn't work. I'll try to put the main activity itself plus its' XML layout.

Comment: @BidhanA It does work on a clean project, as explained in edited.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out recently that the facebook login button caused the problem, since everything worked when it was commented out.

So basically to solve this problem use another method to show the button instead using support fragment manager; sdk docs has lots of examples.