# How to change default font in android applications above lollipop version?

Tags: android, fonts

Am new for android development i need to set custom fonts for whole application for that i have written:

```
public class TypeFaceUtil {
   public static void overrideFont(Context context, String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) {
        final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Map<String, Typeface> newMap = new HashMap<String, Typeface>();
            newMap.put("SERIF", customFontTypeface);
            try {
                final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                        .getDeclaredField("sSystemFontMap");
                staticField.setAccessible(true);
                staticField.set(null, newMap);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                final Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
                defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
                defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TypeFaceUtil.class.getSimpleName(), "Can not set custom font " + customFontFileNameInAssets + " instead of " + defaultFontNameToOverride);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and i call it in application class like this:

```
public class tt extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
       TypeFaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(),"SERIF","fonts/calibri.ttf");
    }
}
```

My fonts is not working in lollipop or above versions and i tried in this method too [Custom Fonts not working in lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27269264/5498065)  how to create a custom fonts which supports all version thanks in advance

Comment: Fonts will not "work" unless you set them by calling  setTypeface() method of textview, button, or other view .

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution so i like to share my solution for future study i have override the default font in value-21 file need to remove the typeface item in your theme  inorder to work with custom fonts.

Answer (score 0):

add this library compile 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'

and this code inside your onCreate

```
Calligrapher calligrapher = new Calligrapher(this);
calligrapher.setFont(this, "fonts/calibri.ttf", true);
```

Comment: can it be used in application class

Answer (score 0):

this SO post has already answered beautifully [How to set default font family for entire Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404820/how-to-set-default-font-family-for-entire-android-app) by **tomrozb** 
Just add this in your values-21.xml file